# Dagger 2, Providing Application Context in Module

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Im pretty new in Android development and newer in DI. I am using Kotlin on a personal project where I am experimenting with Dagger 2. I managed to set it up for a util class, but where i need to have a context to use it to inject a class that requires a context (a sharedpref manager class), I failed. Here is my code, and here is the error ( NPE ) i am getting. Thank you in advance.

my module class

```
package com.android.pine

import android.content.Context
import com.android.pine.utils.SharedPreferencesManager
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun context(pineApplication: PineApplication): Context = pineApplication.applicationContext

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSharedPrefManager(context: Context): SharedPreferencesManager = SharedPreferencesManager(context)
}
```

my component class:

```
package com.android.pine

import com.android.pine.home.HomePresenter
import com.android.pine.home.categories.CategoryAdapter
import dagger.Component
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class))
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(categoryAdapter: CategoryAdapter)
    fun inject(homePresenter: HomePresenter)
}
```

edit: added the info below, 
How I call the inject of sharedPreferencesManager:

```
class HomePresenter : BasePresenter<HomeView>() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPreferencesManager: SharedPreferencesManager
.
.
.
```

Also in my HomePresenter class, in onAttached method override:

```
 DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this)
```

My pineApplication class and SharedPrefManager class looks like this:

```
class PineApplication @Inject constructor(): Application()
```

SharedPref:

```
class SharedPreferencesManager @Inject constructor(context: Context) {
.
.
.
```

Crash, can not get the pineApplication.getContext() (edited, added the full stack trace)

```
     06-02 11:57:01.028 14840-14840/com.android.pine.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.pine.debug, PID: 14840
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.pine.debug/com.android.pine.home.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3429)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
    at com.android.pine.AppModule.context(AppModule.kt:12)
    at com.android.pine.AppModule_ContextFactory.proxyContext(AppModule_ContextFactory.java:34)
    at com.android.pine.DaggerAppComponent.getContext(DaggerAppComponent.java:29)
    at com.android.pine.DaggerAppComponent.getSharedPreferencesManager(DaggerAppComponent.java:34)
    at com.android.pine.DaggerAppComponent.injectHomePresenter(DaggerAppComponent.java:59)
    at com.android.pine.DaggerAppComponent.inject(DaggerAppComponent.java:49)
    at com.android.pine.home.HomePresenter.onAttached(HomePresenter.kt:31)
    at com.android.pine.home.HomePresenter.onAttached(HomePresenter.kt:10)
    at com.android.pine.core.BaseActivity.onResume(BaseActivity.kt:34)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1269)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6783)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3406)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace and the code where/how you call/inject it, this seems rather odd

Comment: edited the post, added some more information, apologies for incompleteness in the question

Comment: There are several errors in your code based on a misunderstanding of both Android and Dagger. This is ok, we all experience this. One problem I see is you're injecting a presenter, but since you control that class entirely, you should just use constructor injection. Take a look at this blog which explains in detail how to set up an Android project with Dagger https://dev.to/autonomousapps/the-daggerandroid-missing-documentation-33kj

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how It is done. Using @BindsInstance in your component will inject application to all of your modules.In your case just to AppModule

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class))
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder() {
        fun build(): AppComponent

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
    }
}
```

** Delete code to "Provides application" function in your APP module and make sure you pass application context to create sharedPreferences.

```
@Module
class AppModule {


@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideSharedPrefManager(context: Application): SharedPreferencesManager = 
    SharedPreferencesManager(context)
}
```

and now in your onCreate of applicationClass

```
DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
```

Optional: if you want to inject something into your applicationClass then do the following

```
 DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build().inject(this)
```

Comment: WHY could I not find any answer on any post with this simple and WORKING example. I swear to god I was going to jump out the window had I not found this

Comment: If I understand correctly, I take the context in MainActivity and build AppComponent there. But then I need to inject something, e.g. a fragment. I don't have that context there, so how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `class PineApplication @Inject constructor(): Application()` to create `PineApplication`. It's a framework class and has to be created by the Android Framework.

Doing so Dagger will create `PineApplication`, but `applicationContext` will return `null` as it has never been initialized (by the system).

Don't use constructor injection for framework classes and don't create the yourself. Use `@Bindsintance` to add the object to the component with its builder, or use a module to provide it.

Comment: could you please give an example how to use @BindInstance in this case ?

Comment: @tipi You can [check the javadoc](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.16/dagger/BindsInstance.html) or see the [users guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide#binding-instances) for an example

Answer (score 3):

You can try modifying your App module like this.

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(private val application: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(): Context {
        return application.applicationContext
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSharedPreferences(context: Context): SharedPreferences {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
}
```

Then you can build the dagger component like this from your Application class.

```
val appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
                .build()
```

Inject values in presenter like this.

```
application.appComponent.inject(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

For provide application context, you can create class, like `ComponentsManager`
with:

```
public class ComponentsManager {

    private Context context;
    private AppComponent appComponent;

    public ComponentsManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent(){
        if (appComponent == null){
            appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                    .appModule(new AppModule(context))
                    .build();
        }
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

And in your application class init this `ComponentsManager` like this:

```
public class YourApp extends Application {

    private static ComponentsManager componentsManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initComponentsManager();
        initAppComponent();
    }

    public static ComponentsManager getComponentsManager(){
        return componentsManager;
    }

    private void initComponentsManager(){
        componentsManager = new ComponentsManager(this);
    }

    private void initAppComponent(){
        componentsManager.getAppComponent();
    }
}
```